# Fundamental Solution of one dimensional wave operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification

Let $\delta(\mu, \eta) = \delta(\mu) \delta(\eta)$, I showed the function $F(\mu, \eta) = -H(-\mu)H(\eta)$ is a fundamental solution of $L= \partial^2/ \partial \mu\partial\eta$, where $H$ is the Heaviside function and a solution is fundamental for $L$ if it satisfies for $Lu = \delta$.

However, in order to obtain a fundamental solution for the one dimensional wave operator $\partial_{tt} -c^2 \partial_{xx}$, I have to use change of variable $\mu = x+ct, \eta = x -ct $ to obtain the fundamental solution but I am stuck at here and not sure how to proceed.

Edit: My first attempt is as follows but not sure whether is correct or not:

Since $F(\mu, \eta)$ is fundamental solution of L, it means
\begin{align*}
\langle F, L^{'}v \rangle &= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial \mu \partial \eta}(-H(-\mu)H(\eta)) v(\mu, \eta) d\mu d\eta \quad \forall v \in C^{\infty}_{0}(\mathbb{R^n})
\end{align*}

Since $\mu =x + ct, \eta =x-ct$, then we have Jacobian of transformation is $2c$.
Changing variable and using the fact that $F_{tt} -c^2F_{xx} =-4c^2F_{\mu \eta}$, the above equation then becomes

\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \frac{2c}{-4c^2} \Big[(-H(-x-ct)H(x-ct))_{tt}-c^2((-H(-x-ct)H(x-ct))_{xx}) \Big]v(x,y)dxdy
= \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \Big[\frac{1}{2c}H(-x-ct)H(x-ct)\Big]_{tt}-c^2\Big[\frac{1}{2c}H(-x-ct)H(x-ct)\Big]_{xx}v(x,y)dxdy
\end{align}

Thus, the fundamental solution of the$\partial_{tt} -c^2 \partial_{xx}$ is $\frac{1}{2c}H(-x-ct)H(x-ct)$.

I am not sure whether it is correct or not, any helps/suggestions/corrections would be appreciated.

Comment: Where are you stuck exactly? Change of variables can be done with the chain rule

Comment: yea so by chain rule, I think I got $\delta = u_{tt} -c^2u_{xx} = -4c^2u_{\mu\eta}$ where $u$ is a fundamental solution but then I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @Gregory I've added my attempt but not sure whether this is the right way to do it, can you give me some advice/suggestions?